# c++ linked list strange compiler-error

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list in C++ using the following Code

```
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}

class LList
{
private:
    struct node
    {
        int value;
        node *follower;  // node definitely is a node
    };

    node m_list;
    int m_length;
public:
    LList ();
    void insert (int index, int value);
    int get_length () const { return m_length; }
};

LList::LList ()
{
    m_length = 0;
    m_list.follower = 0;
}
void LList::insert (int index, int value)
{
    node *cur_node = &m_list;
    for (int count=0; count<index; count++)
    {
        cur_node = cur_node.follower;  // << this line fails
    }
}
```

(This is not my original code, so please ignore any unlogic things, bad naming...)

Compiling it with g++ results in the following compiler error

> main.cpp: In member function ‘void LList::insert(int, int)’:
>   main.cpp:33:29: error: request for member ‘follower’ in ‘cur_node’,
>   which is of non-class type ‘LList::node*’

However 'follower' pretty much seems to be a node!?

Notes:
-I am using g++ 4.6.2 using the command

```
g++ main.cpp -Wall -g -o my_program
```

-Working on a fedora 16 64Bit machine

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you making your own linked list in the first place? C++ already has `std::list`.

Comment: @sbi: I have a precognition: "Learning purposes".

Comment: @sbi: I am doing my own list because I wasn't aware of the fact C++ already has them. Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @drakide: Yes! C++ has lots of tools built-in! I'll recommend you [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/46642).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pointers are accessed with `->`:

```
cur_node = cur_node->follower;
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. Pointers are still pretty confusing to me.

Comment: @drakide: If this solved your problem, please click on the little tick right beside the answer to mark this one as "accepted". Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
node *cur_node = &m_list;
```

`cur_node` is pointer of `node`

```
for (int count=0; count<index; count++)
{
    cur_node = cur_node->follower; 
}
```

should work